# Select multiple count queries in single query

Tags: performance, sql, oracle

I currently have 6 very similar queries that I'm trying to increase performance on by making them all subqueries in 1 query. I'm not sure what is better performance wise, keeping them 6 separate queries, 1 query with 6 subqueries (as shown below), or some other method that I'm unfamiliar with.

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_one WHERE date=myDate AND name=myName) AS total,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_one WHERE date=myDate AND name=myName AND CODE_A BETWEEN 100 AND 199) AS code_a_low_count,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_one WHERE date=myDate AND name=myName AND CODE_A BETWEEN 200 AND 299) AS code_a_high_count,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_one WHERE date=myDate AND name=myName AND CODE_B BETWEEN 100 AND 199) AS code_b_low_count,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_one WHERE date=myDate AND name=myName AND CODE_B BETWEEN 200 AND 299) AS code_b_high_count,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_one WHERE date=myDate AND name=myName AND CODE_C BETWEEN 100 AND 199) AS code_c_count
FROM table_one
WHERE ROWNUM=1
```

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you use common table expression (Oracle calls it ["Subquery Factoring"](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause)) at the very least you will be doing the filtering by date and name one time only

```
WITH filter_by_date_name AS ( 
  SELECT CODE_A, CODE_B, CODE_C FROM table_one WHERE date=myDate AND name=myName
)
SELECT 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM filter_by_date_name) AS total,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM filter_by_date_name WHERE CODE_A BETWEEN 100 AND 199) AS code_a_low_count,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM filter_by_date_name WHERE CODE_A BETWEEN 200 AND 299) AS code_a_high_count,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM filter_by_date_name WHERE CODE_B BETWEEN 100 AND 199) AS code_b_low_count,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM filter_by_date_name WHERE CODE_B BETWEEN 200 AND 299) AS code_b_high_count,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM filter_by_date_name WHERE CODE_C BETWEEN 100 AND 199) AS code_c_count
FROM filter_by_date_name
WHERE ROWNUM=1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple task for *conditional aggregation* using CASEs:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS total,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN CODE_A BETWEEN 100 AND 199 THEN 1 END) AS code_a_low_count,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN CODE_A BETWEEN 200 AND 299 THEN 1 END) AS code_a_high_count,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN CODE_B BETWEEN 100 AND 199 THEN 1 END) AS code_b_low_count,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN CODE_B BETWEEN 200 AND 299 THEN 1 END) AS code_b_high_count,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN CODE_C BETWEEN 100 AND 199 THEN 1 END) AS code_c_count
FROM table_one
WHERE date=myDate AND name=myName
```

As you're COUNTing you can return anything (besides NULL) in THEN.

This can also be written as a SUM over 1/0:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN CODE_A BETWEEN 100 AND 199 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a *late* answer; nonetheless, here you go, a different approach: instead of querying the same table "n" times, do it once. Instead of `count`, use `sum` with `decode`.

```
select 
  count(*) total,
  sum(case when code_a between 100 and 199 then 1 else 0 end) code_a_low_count,
  sum(case when code_a between 200 and 299 then 1 else 0 end) code_a_high_count,
  sum(case when code_b between 100 and 199 then 1 else 0 end) code_b_low_count,
  sum(case when code_b between 200 and 299 then 1 else 0 end) code_b_high_count,
  sum(case when code_c between 100 and 199 then 1 else 0 end) code_c_count
from table_one
where date = mydate
and name = myname;
```

Answer (score 0):

The real Jedi Knight way here is to use the force of `PIVOT`/`UNPIVOT` feature.

```
with t as (
    select 'myname' myname, sysdate mydate, 100 CODE_A, 199 CODE_B, 222 CODE_C from dual union all
    select 'myname' myname, sysdate mydate, 234 CODE_A, 200 CODE_B, 135 CODE_C from dual union all
    select 'myname' myname, sysdate mydate, 155 CODE_A, 124 CODE_B, 299 CODE_C from dual
    ),
  precalc as (
    select myname, mydate, floor(CODE_A/100) CODE_A, floor(CODE_B/100) CODE_B, floor(CODE_C/100) CODE_C
      from t),
  unpiv as (
    select myname, mydate, col_name || col_val name_and_val
      from precalc
   unpivot (col_val for col_name in ("CODE_A","CODE_B","CODE_C")))
select *
  from unpiv
 pivot (count(*) for name_and_val in (
   'CODE_A1' code_a_low_count, 'CODE_A2' code_a_high_count, 
   'CODE_B1' code_b_low_count, 'CODE_B2' code_b_high_count, 
   'CODE_C1' code_c_low_count, 'CODE_C2' code_c_high_count))
```

How does it work:

- `t` subquery contain sample data;
- `precalc` replaces different numeric values with `1` and `2` for `*_low_count` and `*_high_count`;
- `unpiv` is result of unpivoting (`COL_NAME` and `COL_VAL` are added below to demonstrate the idea, they not present in the query):

  ```
  MYNAME MYDATE   COL_NAME    COL_VAL NAME_AND_VAL 
  ------ -------- -------- ---------- -------------
  myname 13/09/18 CODE_A            1 CODE_A1      
  myname 13/09/18 CODE_B            1 CODE_B1      
  myname 13/09/18 CODE_C            2 CODE_C2      
  myname 13/09/18 CODE_A            2 CODE_A2      
  myname 13/09/18 CODE_B            2 CODE_B2      
  myname 13/09/18 CODE_C            1 CODE_C1      
  myname 13/09/18 CODE_A            1 CODE_A1      
  myname 13/09/18 CODE_B            1 CODE_B1      
  myname 13/09/18 CODE_C            2 CODE_C2
  ```
- Final query is a pivot query calculating counts of occurancies of values `CODE_A1`, `CODE_B1`, etc.:

  ```
  MYNAME MYDATE   CODE_A_LOW_COUNT CODE_A_HIGH_COUNT CODE_B_LOW_COUNT CODE_B_HIGH_COUNT CODE_C_LOW_COUNT CODE_C_HIGH_COUNT
  ------ -------- ---------------- ----------------- ---------------- ----------------- ---------------- -----------------
  myname 13/09/18                2                 1                2                 1                1                 2
  ```